# what does this error from xcode mean?

Tags: objective-c

> 2015-11-18 19:51:21.671 Technology Proficiency[9051:1841086] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
>   Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

Comment: Update your question with the code causing the error.

Comment: You are trying to set a property called `keyPath` on an instance of `UIView` (which doesn't have a `keyPath` property). You need to show your actual code if you want a useful answer.

Comment: give outlet properly. i have solved this error. by reconnecting outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You had an outlet for which you deleted the property from your interface.
Go in your storyboard/xib file, and check which outlet still is connected to a non-existing property.